# WAS MQ 7.0.x prevent mqm user to put message on queue

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I'm new in WAS MQ. I have a qmgr called QM1 and a local queue which called Q1. There is a SVRCONN channel with MCA set to mqm.

I want to prevent incoming message through this channel to PUT message to Q1.
I'm using setmqaut but it's not working as I want.

Comment: Thank you T.Rob. I'm using WAS MQ 7.0.1.8. Actually there is no Completion code and Reason code or any exceptions. The issue is that I have two queues (Q1, Q2); there is an application that want to get message from Q1 do something and put the result in Q2. Can I use MCA User ID for do that. I want to do something like authentication.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question backwards.  I thought you were saying that the `mqm` ID was being blocked, not that it was getting through.  Please see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you haven't been able to prevent specific API calls over that channel is that the `MCAUSER('mqm')` setting ensures that anything connecting over that channel *always* connects with full administrative authority.  There is no way to use `setmqaut` or any other native WMQ feature to prevent an administrator from accessing the queue.  The QMgr always allows access by the admin, regardless of any `setmqaut` settings.

It is a bit unclear as to what to recommend because there's no such thing as "WAS MQ".  There is WebSphere Application Server (WAS) and there's WebSphere MQ (WMQ).  WAS used to come bundled with WMQ but the two are not a single product.

Assuming that you mean WebSphere MQ and not WebSphere App Server talking to WMQ, I'd strongly recommend moving to a modern version.  End-of-Life has been announced for WMQ v7.0 and it lacks authentication features of versions v7.1 and higher.  As of v8.0, WMQ can even authenticate a user ID and password.

In order to authenticate and apply granular authorization in WMQ, you will need to use some value *other* than 'mqm' in the `MCAUSER` of the channel.  The standard advice is to set the `MCAUSER` of all channels of type `RCVR`, `RQSTR`, `CLUSRCVR` and `SVRCONN` to `*NOBODY` and then arrange to authenticate your channels based on something useful such as the Distinguished Name of a certificate. Other less useful ways to validate a connection (because these can hardly be called "authentication") include looking at the IP address of the inbound connection or the identity that is claimed on a `SVRCONN`.

In v7.0, these require an exit and [`BlockIP2`](http://mrmq.dk) is the standard used throughout the WMQ install base world-wide. In v7.1 and v7.5 you can achieve the same thing simply through configuration of `CHLAUTH` rules using standard `MQSC` scripting.

There are several conference presentations discussing how to do this at [t-rob.net](http://t-rob.net) on the [Links](http://t-rob.net/links) page.  I would *strongly* recommend moving to v7.5 of WMQ, especially since [you can do so for free](http://ibm.co/MQ75Advanced4Devs) as a developer, regardless of the status of the licensing that the company running the QMgr has purchased.  However, the QMgr in Production can also be upgraded to v7.5 for free if it is under maintenance.  If you wait until June you can have v8.0, although the availability of a free developer version has not been announced as yet, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you T.Rob. In v7.5 how can I want other applications who want to connect to my QMGR set username and password? Is that possible at all?

Comment: It is possible with WMQ v8.0 which is due out in June.  Older versions of WMQ require a channel security exit to validate a password. Capitalware sells such an exit or it is possible to write one, though not recommended.  The problem with writing one is that it requires system-level, recursive, reentrant, thread-safe C code. Most shops don't have that skill in-house or are willing to maintain that skill in-house for one component. That leads to a lot of consulting work for me and a lot of outages for customers. So wait for v8.0, use certificates, or call Capitalware.

Comment: thank you for your response. But there is another question. I have a qmgr QM1 and local queues Q1 and Q2. There is a SVRCONN channel with MCA set to mqm.

There are multiple application connect to my QMGR for example APP1 and App2. I want App1 only have PUT authority which means ONLY PUT message to Q1 or Q2 and App2 only have GET authority to ONLY GET message from Q1 or Q2.

Comment: Each unique set of authorizations needs to be attached to a group.  Then when the app connects it needs to do so as a user ID in the appropriate group. (Remember that access requests always resolve to a specific principal, but authorizations are attached to groups.)  Once you have groups for app1 and app2, then you need to arrange that the MCAUSER of the *running* channel is a user ID in the appropriate group.  You can do this by having different channels with hard-coded MCAUSER in each, or dynamically set the MCAUSER based on CHLAUTH rules.

Comment: Thank you @T.Rob. I asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730710/was-mq-7-5-x-queue-access-control. I'm going to define 2 channels for each applications and also define 2 groups for them.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a very long time to solve this and also I read [T.Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214668/t-rob) presentations especially [this](http://t-rob.net/Downloads/20120501_1577-WebSphere_MQ_Securing_Your_Queue_Manager.pdf) one. Finally I choose the solution to define `CHLAUTH` for check through which `IP` want to connect to my channel.

I add below `CHLAUTH` to my Queue Manager, It works.

```
SET CHLAUTH('SVRCONN') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('ALLOWANY') WARN(YES) ACTION(ADD)
SET CHLAUTH('SVRCONN') TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('*') USERSRC(NOACCESS)
SET CHLAUTH('SVRCONN') TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS('192.168.148.40-60') MCAUSER('mqm')
```

I also recommend to see [this](http://www.midvision.com/community/code-blog-for-developers/bid/275523/WMQ-7-1-Channel-Authentication).